# How to denied downloading a specific file

Tags: 11.10, downloads

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 in my Uncle's PC and since then he has downloaded Ashampoo 149 times. I do not know why he has downloaded that 149 times and tried to install it 149 times the thing is, that file is about 150MB. He downloads that file about 2-3 times a day and it is getting very annoying when anyone wants to use the shared internet connection.

I want to denied the download of this file. If I can in one or any of the following ways:

1. Actually denied the download of that file from that specific url link.
2. Denied any download from that site, the Ashampoo site in this case.
3. Denied the download of ANY file that has the name Ashampoo in it.

Comment: Funny question :D
just blacklist that website 
i dont know how to do it in ubuntu

may be'nanny'  app may help you :)

Comment: Actually yes, some nanny app would help. In this case a granny app.

Comment: Nanny is a name of a parntl cntrl app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are awesome(Getting on someones PC and Kicking him away :-)) I am not a geek like you but i think you could give a try to the UFW (Default Firewall), It'll cover almost all of your needs. I do not got more info about this stuff, but it is the perfect way (UFW is a command line tool, GUFW is the GUI tool to configure it)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try to educate your uncle and help him install software to do what he is trying to use ashampoo for?

But for the purpose of the actual question it depends on your routers firmware. In Gargoyle for instance you could go to firewall - restrictions then add a new rule that blocks website url ashampoo.com (or just the download one if you have it) for all hosts.